# spring cloud stream- consumer config not working

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I am using spring boot 2.0.3-RELEASE version. This is my config file.
When I start my consumer then its start with default configuration.They are not override by my specified config.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost
          defaultBrokerPort: 9092
          zkNodes: localhost
          defaultZkPort: 2181
       bindings:
         inEvent:
           consumer:
             configuration:
               max:
                 poll:
                   records: 10
               group:
                 id: group1
               client:
                 id: 1
               enable:
                 auto:
                   commit: true
               auto:
                 offset:
                   reset: earliest
           group: eventin
           destination: event
         inSenser:
           consumer:
             configuration:
               max:
                 poll:
                   records: 10
               client:
                 id: 2
           group: insenser
           destination: processenser
```

This is my i/o channel interface.

```
interface EventStream {

    @Input("inEvent")
    fun getEvents(): SubscribableChannel

    @Input("inSenser")
    fun getSensers(): SubscribableChannel
}
```

Comment: Where is your config file in your project? How is your project being packaged/executed?

Comment: Hi @CraigOtis my config is present in application.yml file in my project resource directory.And my project is gradle build.I resolve the problem I change spring.cloud.stream.binding to spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binding. Can you tell me diff bw both of these property and any link where i understand the diff bw them

Answer (score 0):

I think both spring.cloud.stream.binding and spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binding will work for you in this case. Seems this is format error. Please check your yaml file's format and give a try. Thanks.

[format is not correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuAhr.png)